# Is the Firebase Console "Data View" always downloading my full realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Let's say we have a database of 10 GB with a structure like that (with more books, etc):

[image: Taken from: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible]

What happens if I open this database in the Data View of the Firebase console?

I've learned that with the realtime database it's not possible to just read the keys of an object.
How does the Data View know the subkeys of the root (such as "channels", "input") without downloading all the contained data. Further more:

**Do I have to wait until "channels" is completely downloaded to see "inbox"?**

**Did I then cause 10 GB download costs?** (assumed I wait accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is large the Firebase console switches to "read-only" mode. In that mode the console uses the REST API to download a shallow listing of only the keys of the level you're seeing. This should drastically reduce the amount of data it downloads.

Comment: I see. Can you explain, why the shallow read of keys option is only supported by the REST API? Some use cases would benefit from a shallow read. For instance, counting the child nodes (less data costs). What I understand CON: You have to download all keys (No limits). PRO: You don't need to manage multiple duplication of data. The Data View itself is a good example of a use case.